# Does ; means anything inside SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Ok I typed this to google and no answer

Here comes my question

Assume that inside a stored procedure I have the following selects would it make any difference putting `;` at the end of select statements or not?

I mean if I do not put `;` at the end of statement what happens? And if I put what happens?

```
begin

declare @param_1 int;
declare @param_2 int;

select @param_1 = col1 from mytable
select @param_2 = col2 from mytable

end
```

Case 1 above no ; at the end

```
begin

declare @param_1 int;
declare @param_2 int;

select @param_1 = col1 from mytable;
select @param_2 = col2 from mytable;

end
```

Case 2 above ; at the end

**I am not asking for this particular case. It will obviously have no effect on this example but in run time what difference does it make ? I mean does it complete it then move next or what**

Thanks for the answers

Comment: `;` is the standard for terminating a statement. Without it, your lines will all be considered a SINGLE statement - sql doesn't consider linebreaks to be significant.

Comment: Some statements like `Merge` and `With` require a `;` at the end or right before the statement.  Essentially, it's terminating the preceding statement(s).  There is no difference in these examples.

Comment: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms143729.aspx in some future version of SQL Server, semicolons will be required always. (It may be some time, though...)

Comment: Semicolon is a (mostly optional) *syntax* element.  It has no effect on execution or peformance, only on parsing the syntax.

Comment: in the environment of the SQL Analyzer or SQL Server management studio, the `;` is almost optional. However when executing some continuous queries/commands (all in a string) such as in `C#` code, you do need to use the `;` to separate the queries/commands.

Comment: @KingKing: Can you back that up with an example?

Comment: @Andomar I've experienced with this before, such as there are some queries in a string like this `"create table table1 (...) create table table2 (...) create table table3 (....) ...."`, you do need the `;` to separate the `create` like this `"create table table1 (...) ; create table table2 (...) ; create table table3 (....);  ...."` and such as use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` to run it. It's a long time ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `;` terminates a statement.  In most cases it's optional.  Whether you terminate a statement implicitly (without a semicolon) or explicitly (with a semicolon) makes no difference.  [MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)

> Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon is not
>   required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be
>   required in a future version.

Here's an example where `;` is not currently optional.  This will fail:

```
select 6
with t1 as (select 7 as col1) select * from t1
```

While this will work:

```
select 6
; with t1 as (select 7 as col1) select * from t1
```

A `with` or `merge` statement requires the preceding statement to be explicitly terminated.

Comment: `... it will be required in a future version` - Sure it will.  How many thousands of hours of modifying code would that require for everyone?  I don't see that ever happening.

Comment: So we can say that it is better to always use ; - can there be any scenarios that we would want to avoid ?

Comment: `;` is always okay, but there is no benefit in using it where it is optional

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG there is no downside to using it, so, as a good habit for writing portable code, it is always better to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, it means that the statement ending with the ';' must complete/finish/terminate before the next line will begin executing.

Comment: True, but just a side effect of terminating statements.  An implicitly terminated statement (without a semicolon) has to finish too before the next statement can begin executing.

Answer (score 1):

Not using a semicolon to terminate statements is a deprecated behavior (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx). Whether or not it will actually be disallowed in future versions is irrelevant; it is deprecated and therefore should not be done. All statements should use a semicolon as a terminating character. Further, using semicolons help code readability.